# How to show a sidebar in a spreadsheet where you are not the owner?

Tags: html, vue.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm developing a Google Spreadsheet Add-on with GAS.
I want to switch sidebars using `HtmlService` class method.

Below is my code.

```js
function showSidebarA() {
  const ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html/A").evaluate().setTitle("sidebarA");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function showSidebarB() {
  const ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html/B").evaluate().setTitle("sidebarB");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

There are buttons in the sidebar's HTML markup.
We can switch sidebars by pushing buttons.

However, it doesn't work well.

I failed to switch sidebars in the spreadsheet that I'm not the owner, but only the editor.

I don't know what to do, because there are no error messages.

---

Code for first displaying a sidebar

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  if (e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('sidebarA', 'showSidebarA')
      .addToUi();
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('sidebarB', 'showSidebarB')
      .addToUi();
  }
}

function onInstall(e){
  onOpen(e);
}
```

Code related to the buttons in the sidebars

sidebarA.html

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-btn icon @click="showSidebarB">
        <v-icon large>mdi-arrow-left-bold-circle<v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    <v-app>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    methods: {
      showSidebarB: function() {
        google.script.run.showSidebarB();
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

sidebarB.html

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-btn icon @click="showSidebarA">
        <v-icon large>mdi-arrow-left-bold-circle<v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    <v-app>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    methods: {
      showSidebarA: function() {
        google.script.run.showSidebarA();
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to the buttons in the sidebars and also the code for first displaying a sidebar? Also, I assume you're `testing` the add-on, right? What authorization mode are you following, `AuthMode.NONE` (just installed) or `AuthMode.LIMITED` (enabled)? In any case, I think your issue is due to: `Add-ons can't open sidebars or dialogs while executing in AuthMode.LIMITED. You can use menu items to open sidebars and dialogs since these run in AuthMode.FULL.` [ref](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled)

Comment: Dear Jamm, please *do not* include tag name as the title prefix with or without syling. It is noisy and does not help the post in any way. What it achieves, though, is putting additional work on editors of the site. Thank you!

Comment: Also, please show your sidebar markup and how it is loaded. P.s. it is likely due to multiple logins. Open DevTools if you are on Chrome (or any other similar tool) and look for the Network tab. Clear it and click on a button. You will see a call to Google's servers - inspect the response. It will likely contain an authorization issue error (despite returning a 200 successful response)

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks for your advice! I have added codes to this post. The code for first displaying a sidebar works well. But, the other doesn't work.

Comment: @OlegValter I check the AuthMode of both owner or not. Their Auth mode are 'LIMITED'. I think that the cause is Google Workspace(G suite). Account that can switch sidebars is Google Workspace(G suite) account. But, the other that cannot do it is not. It is Personal Account.